# Retry on Mono seems to generate an infinite loop

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to learn Reactor and I created the following example:

```
  fun dbThingErrorSometimes() : Mono<String> {
        return if (Random.nextBoolean()){
            processDbResult(pooledClient.execute("SELECT * FROM product"))
        }else{
            Mono.error(RuntimeException("boom"))
        }
    }
```

then where it is used I do (in a controller):

```
 @RequestMapping("/dbpooledretry")
    @ResponseBody
    fun dbExamplePoolRetrying(): Mono<String> {
        return dbService.dbThingErrorSometimes()
                .retry()
    }
```

when it comes out with an error it gets stuck in an infinite loop (rest call never returns and cpu goes 100%). Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `retry()` method just retries the publisher returned by `dbService.dbThingErrorSometimes()`, which might be a `Mono.error()`. `dbService.dbThingErrorSometimes()` never gets re-called, the publisher it emits just gets re-subscribed to.

So if it *does* emit an error, then resubscribing to that same error publisher isn't ever going to change the outcome, hence your infinite loop.

Instead, you likely want to make the `Mono` lazy, re-calling `dbService.dbThingErrorSometimes()` each time you retry - you can achieve this by wrapping that method call in [`Mono.defer()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-).

Answer (score -1):

As the documentation states [Mono#retry](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retry--)

> Re-subscribes to this Mono sequence if it signals any error,
>   **indefinitely**.

So this is as intended, it will retry for the rest of our lives.